# What is calling didUpdateLocations in my Swift code?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I am learning Swift, and in the snippet code below there is a `locationManager` method. Why should I write this even though it has not been called in the action code of the Locate me button?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: `UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate` {
  @IBOutlet weak var Mapview: MKMapView!
  var manager = CLLocationManager()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let pinLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5078788, -0.08773210000003928)
    let objectAnn = MKPointAnnotation()
    objectAnn.coordinate = pinLocation
    objectAnn.title = "London Bridge"
    objectAnn.subtitle = "London, United kingdom"
    self.Mapview.addAnnotation(objectAnn)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  @IBAction func Directions(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=51.5078788,-0.08773210000003928")!)
  }

  @IBAction func LocateMe(sender: AnyObject) {
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    Mapview.showsUserLocation = true
  }

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userlocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userlocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userlocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

    Mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve using above code ? is you want display only current location than no need for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called delegate.

you are implementing `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

Since you are setting your `manager` delegate to the view controller by using this code `manager.delegate = self` it will automatically called delegate event in certain condition.

In your code, if your location is updated, the view controller will automatically run this function `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`

Comment: Thanks a lot for that , word "delegate" makes a lot of isseus a dose not understand about swift  clear

Comment: @mahmoudgamal In the concept of delegation you pass actions and in this case events (when locations did update) to another object which is called "delegate". Here you set the `ViewController` to the delegate of the location manager so this method gets called every time the locations did update.

Answer (score 2):

The code in question is this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
```

I realise you're learning Swift right now, so it might be strange to have code that you don't call yourself. But in this example, the code gets called by iOS.

You see, when you write `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` it has the effect that iOS wants to start telling you when the user's location has changed. It does that by looking to see if you have the `didUpdateLocations` method above. If you have that method in your code, iOS will call it for you – it's not one you will call yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your function LocateMe(sender:) you are calling `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` this tells the `CLLocationManager` to start looking for your (i guess) gps coordinates. However now every time your location is being updated this `CLLocationManager` will call the function `locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]`. 
This is because the updates are asynchronous, and once your location was updated, you are then notified with this function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply ,

Answer (score 0):

In the `LocateMe` method you are setting the `delegate` of the locationManager to your controller.

the `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`
 method is called when the location changes.

For further information check this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations:

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in .plist and then set location and try this